# Run interactive shell script in new buffer using elisp

Tags: eshell, process, interactive

I am looking for a way to display and interact with long running shell scripts in a separate buffer. While using `eshell` works, I'd like to automate most shell tasks using elisp.

The best way I came up with is (example for `git pull`):

```
(let ((new-buffer (get-buffer-create "*script*")))
     (switch-to-buffer-other-window new-buffer)
     (eshell-command "git pull" t)))
```

While this displays procedural output in a new buffer, emacs locks until the process finishes and I can't interact with git if it prompts for information.

`(start-process "script" new-buffer "git" "pull")` runs asynchronously, but does not accept interactive input either.

The `git pull` command is just an example here.

## Update:

I think I got everything I wanted using `make-comint-in-buffer`. I got correct ansi-colors and can interact with the process if it reads stdin.

Just the gist:

```
(let* ((script-proc-buffer 
           (apply 'make-comint-in-buffer "script" new-buffer "git" nil '("pull")))
       (script-proc (get-buffer-process script-proc-buffer)))

    (set-process-sentinel script-proc 'special-mode-sentinel))
```

Where `special-mode-sentinel` is a defun that switches to `special-mode` when the process has finished, allowing me to quit the buffer using <kbd>q</kbd>.

It's not pretty, but it works...

Comment: Did you already take a look at (elisp) [`Asynchronous Processes`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Asynchronous-Processes.html)?

Comment: Yes, that's where I found `start-process` and `start-process-shell-command`. `start-process-shell-command` almost does what I want, but I can't figure out how to interact with the process if it prompts for input (e.g. a password). But I'm quite new to elisp, so maybe I am missing something...

Comment: The [(elisp) Filter Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Filter-Functions.html) part is where you want to look at. PS catching git password prompts requires a pty, so it won't work under Windows.

Comment: @npostavs Reading up on the filter functions led me to `comint-mode` (which may be overkill). Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the following function

```
(async-shell-command "git pull" "*script*")
```